# Two javascript 'changeimage' functions, only one is working

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I am learning javascript and I have a problem with changeimage function.

I need to change both one, and second image.

Here is jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ewjoxnv/1/

And here below, javascript:

```
var switchingImage;

function changeImage()
{
        switchingImage.src = this.value;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var radios = document.getElementById('imageSwitcher').getElementsByTagName('input');
    switchingImage = document.getElementById('imageToSwitch');
    for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
    {
        radios[i].onclick = changeImage;
    }

    var radios = document.getElementById('imageSwitcher2').getElementsByTagName('input');
    switchingImage = document.getElementById('imageToSwitch2');
    for(var o=0;o<radios.length;o++)
    {
        radios[o].onclick = changeImage;
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Best Regards,
David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var radio =` and `switchingImage =` for the second time, you are changing their previous values.

In the case of `radios` it just happens and does not affect you because you have already applied the listeners you wanted to the old radio buttons.

In the case of `switchingImage` however, it affects you, because `switchingImage` will ultimately point to the `document.getElementById('imageToSwitch2')`. So when you call `changeImage()` it will always operate on `document.getElementById('imageToSwitch2')`.

Here's *one* way you could solve your problem. It is purposefully not the best solution. Use it as a baseline to improve on it.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ewjoxnv/4/

Comment: Thank You Mitch for Your professional approach!
It works perfectly and I will upgrade it from this point easly!